# Calculate the sum of distances between Pattern and each string in Dna = {Dna1, ..., Dnat}

Tags: python, pattern-matching

I am writing a function to compute d(Pattern, Dna) = ∑ti=1 d(Pattern, Dnai), the sum of distances between Pattern and each string in Dna = {Dna1, ..., Dnat}.

Sample Input:

AAA

TTACCTTAAC GATATCTGTC ACGGCGTTCG CCCTAAAGAG CGTCAGAGGT

Sample Output:

5

Below is my code:

```
dna_list = ['TTACCTTAAC', 'GATATCTGTC', 'ACGGCGTTCG', 'CCCTAAAGAG', 'CGTCAGAGGT']
k = 3
k_mer = 'AAA'
hamming_distance = 0
distance = 0

def HammingDistance(s1, s2):
    #Return the Hamming distance between equal-length sequences
    if len(s1) != len(s2):
        raise ValueError("Undefined for sequences of unequal length")
    else:
        return sum(ch1 != ch2 for ch1, ch2 in zip(s1, s2))

for i in xrange(len(dna_list)):
    for j in xrange(len(dna_list[i])-k+1):
        motifs = [dna_list[i][j:j+k]]
        if HammingDistance(k_mer, motifs) > hamming_distance:
            hamming_distance = HammingDistance(k_mer, motifs)
    distance += hamming_distance

print distance
```

When I run the code, it always shows error "Unequal length sequences". I don't understand because each time the code should compute differences between 'motifs'(motifs = [dna_list[i][j:j+k]]) and k_mer (AAA) which have same length.

Comment: your sample input and output have different lengths -- 3 characters vs 10. I don't know why you say they're the same length. Why would a comparison of AAA to five different 10-char strings only give an output of 5?

Comment: @Joseph James  The code 'motifs = [dna_list[i][j:j+k]]' iterating the dna string each time for 3 nucleotides so I think that they are in the same length with the AAA.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The 15 result is correct for the given code.  The greatest hamming distance you can get for each DNA fragment is 3 (each letter different from "AAA")  And you achieve this in each of the five DNA fragments.  Since "distance" is the sum of the greatest hamming distance for each fragment, then 3 x 5 = 15.  Perhaps you intended "distance" to mean something else?

```
dna_list = ['TTACCTTAAC', 'GATATCTGTC', 'ACGGCGTTCG', 'CCCTAAAGAG', 'CGTCAGAGGT']
k_mer = 'AAA'
k_mer_length = len(k_mer)
distance = 0

def HammingDistance(s1, s2):
    """ Return the Hamming distance between equal-length sequences """

    if len(s1) != len(s2):
        raise ValueError("Undefined for sequences of unequal length")

    return sum(ch1 != ch2 for ch1, ch2 in zip(s1, s2))

for index, dna in enumerate(dna_list):

    greatest_hamming_distance = 0

    for offset in range(len(dna) - k_mer_length + 1):

        motif = dna[offset:offset + k_mer_length]

        hamming_distance = HammingDistance(k_mer, motif)

        if hamming_distance > greatest_hamming_distance:
            greatest_hamming_distance = hamming_distance

    distance += greatest_hamming_distance

print(distance)
```

Answer (score 0):

As a second argument to `HammingDistance` you pass a list:

```
    motifs = [dna_list[i][j:j+k]]
```

which has just one element, and therefore it's length is 1. Just remove the outer `[]`.

As a side note,

```
    for i in xrange(len(dna_list)):
```

is very un-Pythonic. Consider instead

```
    for dna in dna_list:
```

Comment: If I remove the outer [], the result will come out 15 instead of 5. Can you explain why?

Comment: @user5893556 That I have no idea. It is a domain knowledge, which I lack.